# Adding new Items to List replacing old Items in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using below code to loop through items and adding items to list.But While adding items to list, old items in list are getting replaced with new items .
How can I avoid items replacement in list .

```
  var finalMenuList=new List<IMenu>();

        foreach(var menuSKU in iMenuSKUList)
            {

                    var menu = new IMenuSKU();
                    menu=iMenuList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id).ToList()[0];
                    var menuSpecs=new List<IMenuMapping>() ;
                    menuSpecs= iMenuCompleteSKUList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id ).ToList();
                    var media = new List<IMenuMedia>();
                    media = iMediaList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id).ToList();
                    menu.MenuMappings = null;
                    menu.MenuMappings = menuSpecs;
                    menu.MenuMedias = null;
                    menu.MenuMedias = media;
                    finalMenuList.Add(menu);

            }
```

Comment: Also, don't ever use `.ToList()[0]` - you should use `.First()` instead. _This won't fix your current issue._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved with below code

```
foreach(var menuSKU in iMenuSKUList)
            {

                    var menu = new IMenuSKU();
                    menu=iMenuList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id).ToList()[0];
                    var menuSpecs=new List<IMenuMapping>() ;
                    menuSpecs= iMenuCompleteSKUList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id ).ToList();
                    var media = new List<IMenuMedia>();
                    media = iMediaList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id).ToList();
                    menu.MenuMappings = null;
                    menu.MenuMappings = menuSpecs;
                    menu.MenuMedias = null;
                    menu.MenuMedias = media;
   // issue has been resolved by creating new instance of object and reassigning it's properties with values as below and finally storing it in list.
                    var finalList = new IMenuSKU
                        {
                            MenuMappings = menu.MenuMappings,
                            MenuMedias  = menu.MenuMedias,
                           //bind remaining properties here
                        };                  

              finalMenuList.Add(finalList);

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is, that you modify object from original List before you add it to final List.

```
menu=iMenuList.Where(a => a.Id == menuSKU.Id).ToList()[0];
```

Here the `menu` object is taken from `iMenuList` and then modified

```
menu.MenuMappings = null;
```

That causes your objects from original List to be modified.
If you want to change object that is passed to finalList, but don't want to modify one that is stored in original List than you must work with copy the new object (clone).

Comment: And there are many lines that should be written in another way, but that was already mentioned in comments

Comment: But we need to loop through 100 of items and add them to list. We can't create 100's of static objects in loop. How can I create dynamic unique objects in above logic

Comment: Now, the same object is in original and final list. When you modify such an object, it is modified in both collections. So yes, to prevent from such a issue you need to create a clone of original object before putting it into final List. You can use serialization or manually create the new object and fill it with required values. I don't see the reason why you mentioned these object as `static`. There is nothing static in creating a new object

Comment: Tried below logic to clone original object data and then inserted to List but still facing same issue.                    var finalList = new IMenu();  
                        finalList = menu; // Copying data to new Object 
                        finalMenuList.Add(finalList);

Comment: I don't see any object copying in above code. What I see is passing reference to `menu` object in variable finalList to finalMenuList collection

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code of the resolution suggested.

Comment: Thanks @TomasChabada, Issue has been resolved. Posted answer below

Comment: That's what I mentioned, manually creating the new object and filling it with required values (of value type). It works because value type Properties are assigned by value, what means there is new value created and it prevents from rewriting such a properties from another object.

Answer (score -1):

You can override Equals method in your class to return something unique for each of objects. This will avoid replacement of objects.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code.It would help me for better understanding.